# LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc

Tags: sprockets, ruby-on-rails-7, dart-sass, rails-sprockets, ruby-3.1

running `rake assets:precompile` ends with the error.
Can't find why it still requires sassc, sassc only was in project when migrated to sprockets 4 using [Guide to upgrading from Sprockets 3.x to 4.x](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#upgrading-as-a-rails-dependency):

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5'
bundle update sass-rails sprockets
```

and then followed dartsass-rails install documentation.
did:

```
rails tmp:clear
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile
```

ruby-3.1.2

```
gem 'rails', '7.0.3.1'
gem 'webrick'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.2'
gem 'dartsass-rails', '~> 0.4.0'
...
```

manifest.js file content:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.css
//= link application.js
//
//= link_tree ../builds
```

error log:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke dartsass:build (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute dartsass:build
+ /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/dartsass-rails-0.4.0/exe/darwin/sass --style\=compressed --no-source-map --load-path 

/app/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/app/assets/builds --load-path 
/app/assets/config --load-path 
/app/assets/fonts --load-path 
/app/assets/images --load-path 
/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/app/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/lib/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/lib/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/vendor/assets/stylesheets --load-path 

/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bundler/gems/flex_calendar-aae0ac1c9b3f/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bundler/gems/flex_calendar-aae0ac1c9b3f/app/assets/images --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bundler/gems/flex_calendar-aae0ac1c9b3f/app/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bundler/gems/flex_calendar-aae0ac1c9b3f/lib/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/flatpickr-4.5.7.0/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bundler/gems/flex_calendar-aae0ac1c9b3f/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/flatpickr-4.5.7.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-5.10.5/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-5.10.5/app/assets/source --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-5.10.5/vendor/assets/config --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.2.6.2/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tinymce-rails-5.10.5/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.2.6.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/select2-rails-4.0.13/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/select2-rails-4.0.13/vendor/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/images --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.3.1/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.3.1/app/assets/stylesheets --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actioncable-7.0.3.1/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/app/assets/javascripts --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionview-7.0.3.1/lib/assets/compiled --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/react-rails-1.9.0/lib/assets/react-source/development --load-path 
/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/react-rails-1.9.0/lib/assets/javascripts/ --load-path 
/app/assets/fonts 
/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:
/app/assets/builds/application.css
  ** Execute assets:precompile
  rake aborted!
  LoadError: cannot load such file -- sassc
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/autoload/sassc.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:42:in `initialize'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:27:in `new'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:27:in `instance'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `fetch'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:27:in `call'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `fetch'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `each'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `to_a'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-4.1.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `block in synchronize'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `synchronize'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:47:in `synchronize'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:22:in `execute'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
 /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
  Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

OS: mac

When I install gem with dependency on sassc-rails (example [pdfjs_viewer-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdfjs_viewer-rails)) and start server with `./bin/dev` , then web starts up and works fine.

Question:
Any idea what could be reason of this and what would be possible solution?

Comment: `sassc` is a dev dependency of sprockets, wondering if that creates a problem because you're running this in `RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: In my setup, `application.css` in the manifest file was a scss file handled by sprockets. Removing this line from the manifest file fixed this error for me. I'm guessing since sprockets detects the SCSS file it tries to load the `sassc` library which may not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the problem:
As under stylesheets root folder were extra `example.scss` file and it was set to precompile with:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( example.css )
```

This errors showed because file actually had different extension.

Solution:

1. Took out example.css from precompilation;
2. Added file for dartsass to handle it using:

```
Rails.application.config.dartsass.builds = {
      "application.scss"    => "application.css",
      "example.scss"        => "example.css"
    }
```

Comment: Just had to add application.css in `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile`. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I fixed it by running `rails tmp:clear` and restarting the server; I did not include any file in my assets.rb file, also this started happening to me when I ran:

```
$ rails importmap:install
$ rails turbo:install stimulus:install
```

Comment: `rails tmp:clear` worked for me too. The way I encountered the "cannot load such file -- sassc" error was by removing all traces of sass from my project (I thought), and then removing `gem "sassc-rails"` from my Gemfile. Clearing tmp files removed any remnants that were tripping up rails. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
# Use Sass to process CSS
gem "sassc-rails"
```

They removed sassc support after 7.0.8 by default!

Comment: Sheesh! In that case, why wouldn't `rails new` create that then. I'm using `"~> 7.1.2"` Come on, Rails! Thanks, Albert.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to better_errors gem to version 2.10.0 also leads to that error, at least with Rails 7 (see https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/issues/516).

A Workaround is preventing the usage of this specific version through something like

```
gem 'better_errors', '!= 2.10.0'
```

Comment: Make sure to mention this to the Better Errors team. They are good guys and will fix it if there is a problem with Better Errors.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue in Rails 7 with jsbundling and cssbundling (not importmaps). It was caused by some files with conflicting names. I had my own slimselect.scss file in the assets folder, but also imported the slimselect css from the 'slimselect' npm package.

Renaming my own file fixed it for me.

Thought I'd mention it here, since none of the above solutions worked, and apparently there are many different causes for this error.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers here are going in totally different directions - which in my opinion well-represents the Rails asset pipeline.

Here's what worked for me

in `manifest.js`

```
//= link_tree ../stylesheets .css
```

The stylesheets folder contained both scss and css. What worked instead was using link_tree for scss files and link for css files.

```
//= link_tree ../stylesheets .scss
//= link other.css
//= link another.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run across this issue as well. Came accross this thread by searching for `cannot load such file -- sass`.

I know that you are using sprockes, but I got this error with webpacker.

In webpacker, the default configuration is not to extract scss in the development environment.
You need to turn this on in `config/webpacker.yml`.

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
  extract_css: true
```

I don't know why this is happening with sprockets, but someone else may have the same issue I was having, and hopefully it helps them.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the below gems in the gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby # to resolve the cannot load such file -- sassc
gem "sassc-rails" # to resolve the cannot load such file -- sassc
```

then bundle install and restart the rails server, This will resolve the issue.